# How to use the word "fit"?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

Which of the following sentences is correct?

> 1. Structure A **fits** a wider variety of situations.
> 2. Structure A **can fit** a wider variety of situations.
> 3. Structure A **is fit for** a wider variety of situations.

Are all of them correct? If so, which one sounds more natural.

Comment: You need to provide more context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All are correct and could sound natural, but which would be preferable will depend on context and the desired implications.

1 and 2 use "fit" as a verb, the difference being that the first is definitive while the second is conditional. If you wanted to sound absolute the first would be the natural choice, but if you wanted to cover the possibility of other things that could affect the situations, the second would be better.

3 uses "fit" as an adjective. Of the three, this one has potential to sound less natural, and may lead to confusion between "appropriate" and "healthy" as synonyms for "fit".

There is a fourth alternative : using "fit" as a noun might be **the best fit** for some contexts.

[Edit : There is more detail and discussion at two of the suggested SE links on the panel to the right, in particular [this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/98013/which-way-can-fit-go?rq=1) and [this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/243218/be-fit-for-fit-or-be-fitting-for-what-is-the-correct-usage-and-why?rq=1).]